# Conditional Formating by groups in excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Was wondering if there was a way to set conditional formatting separately for different groups across the same column. Something like this:

[image]

The idea is that the color scale should be done independently for the groups. In Group 1: 2 is the smallest value and therefore would be red and 50 is the highest and therefore would be green (even though there are values like 114 or 1467, it shouldn't affect this range as it belongs to a different group).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you attempting to color scale within groups? If so, VBA might be the easy way to go and hold your groups in range variables and apply  formatting to those ranges.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to color scale within groups. I haven't really used VBA before though.

Comment: What is the logic for your colour choices? The colors in the cells with the values "2" and "1059" and "107" and "1070" look to be a fairly similar shade of red. Please [edit] your question and explain in words what  you want to achieve.

Comment: Have added a textual description

Answer (score 1):

If colour scaling within groups something like:

```
Public Sub FormatRanges()

    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, rng As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveSheet

        Set rng1 = .Range("B1:B5")
        Set rng2 = .Range("B6:B10")
        Set rng3 = .Range("B11:B15")
        Dim myRanges()
        myRanges = Array(rng1, rng2, rng3)

        For rng = LBound(myRanges) To UBound(myRanges)
           ApplyFormatting myRanges(rng)
        Next rng

    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Sub ApplyFormatting(ByRef rng As Variant)

     rng.FormatConditions.Delete
    rng.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
    rng.FormatConditions(rng.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = _
        xlConditionValueLowestValue
    With rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
        .Color = 7039480
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = _
        xlConditionValuePercentile
    rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
    With rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
        .Color = 8711167
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = _
        xlConditionValueHighestValue
    With rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
        .Color = 8109667
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Example data:

[image: Data]

Code goes in a standard module by pressing Alt + F11 to open VBE and then right click in project and add standard module.

Comment: Did you try the above or need assistance with deploying it?